# $_COOKIE['id'] returns 1 instead of value

Tags: php, setcookie

I am wrestling with an old script I am updating for someone. It stores an id in a cookie on login, then reads it back when loading pages to return the right userdata. Later on I will change it to use sessions, but for now I want this to work...

The problem is that the cookie does get set to the right value (I check it in developer tools), but when I request the value through $_COOKIE['id'] it always returns '1'.

Anybody has an idea why this is happening?

Code:
setting the cookie is in '/modules/users/login.php'

```
setcookie("id", $row['id'], time()+$_POST['tijdingelogd'],'/');
```

EDIT: ADDED INFORMATION
After setting the cookie values, the visitor gets redirected using:

```
header("location:/index.php");
```

Reading the cookie is in '/connection/functions.php

```
echo $_COOKIE['id'];
```

Comment: What is _"the right value"_???

Comment: In my case it should be 2 (and in developer tools I can see that the cookie value is set to 2)

Comment: Are you sure that `$row['id']` is equal two in this case ?

Comment: As I stated, the cookie[ id]  value gets set to 2, I can see that in the developer tools

Comment: `echo $_COOKIE['id'];` will show on a page reload because it's pulling from the cookies on the page, not the cookies that your script is preparing to send.

Comment: Hi Altimus, reloading the page does not change the value I get back. Besides that the values get set on posting of a form on '/modules/users/login.php' after that the visitor gets redirected to page '/index.php' by using `header("location:/index.php");`

Comment: Please don't add "answered" to question title. You have a ✔ icon ("Click to accept this answer") beside answers which is the proper way to tag questions as answered.

Comment: Alvaro, I can only accept my own response as an answer after a set period of time... Hence this workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, during the check whether a visitor was logged in, the value for the cookie was reset to 1 within the script. This was not reflected in the developer tools, hence my confusion.

For future visitors coming to this thread, the code setting the value without it reflecting in developer tools was:

```
$_COOKIE['userid'] = 1;
```

Thanks to all answering to this thread

Comment: `$_COOKIE` stores cookies *received* by PHP. To emit a cookie in the response you use `setcookie()`.